# UNUserNotificationCenter didReceive response not called when app is terminated

Tags: ios, swift, unusernotificationcenter

I'm working on local notifications but the problem I have is that the method didReceive Response is not being called when the app is terminated so when I tap on a notification action it just launches the app and did nothing else. But when the app is just in the background everything works as usual. Anything wrong with my code?

//MyClassNameViewController.swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

}

func triggerAlarm1() {
    // Create an instance of notification center
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    // Sets the details of the notification
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Recorded Today's first alarm."
    content.body = "Be completely honest: how is your day so far?"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
    content.categoryIdentifier = "notificationID1"

    // Set the notification to trigger everyday
    let triggerDaily = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour,.minute], from: myTimePicker1.date)
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDaily, repeats: true)

    // Deliver the notification
    let identifier = "UYLLocalNotification"
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier,
                                        content: content, trigger: trigger)
    center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            // Just in case something went wrong
            print(error!)
        }
    })

}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    print("didReceive Method called")

    if response.actionIdentifier == "actionOne" {
        let alertOne = UIAlertController(title: "First", message: "Some Message Here", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        let actionOne = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)
        alertOne.addAction(actionOne)
        self.present(alertOne, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    completionHandler()
}
```

//AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

    // Request Authorisation
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert , .sound , .badge]) { (Bool, error) in
        // insert code here
    }

    let actionOne = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "actionOne", title: "Open1", options: [.foreground])
    let catogeryOne = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "notificationID1", actions: [actionOne], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([catogeryOne])

    return true
}
```

Comment: Of course! The application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method will be called whenever your app is launched first time. Therefore you'll need a notification from this method and you'll be Ok! Use the NotificationCenter and post notifications to your viewDIdLoad or viewDidAppear methods

Comment: That means I have to implement the delegate methods in my app delegate?

Comment: I found a pattern. When I force kill the app, than the method don't get called the first time.  One time it was called but with a huge delay. Any further notifications would call the function immediately (with the app still terminated).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call this function inside of your action identifier and you'll be ok!

```
 func alertAction() {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Hello", message: "This is cool!", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        // Do something with handler block
    }))

    let pushedViewControllers = (self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController).viewControllers
    let presentedViewController = pushedViewControllers[pushedViewControllers.count - 1]

    presentedViewController.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

It's super easy!

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    print("didReceive Method called")

    if response.actionIdentifier == "actionOne" {
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.alertAction()
        })
    } else if response.actionIdentifier == "actionTwo" {

    } else if response.actionIdentifier == "actionThree" {

    }
    completionHandler()
}
```

Fully works on Swift 3.0 and Xcode 8.0. I have changed all of the connections between the view controller. I've added a `NavigationController` to the initial `ViewController`.

[image: Change the connections to the <code>show</code> instead of the <code>present modally</code>]

AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.


    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.delegate = self

    // Request Authorisation
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert , .sound , .badge]) { (Bool, error) in
        // insert code here
    }

    let actionOne = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "actionOne", title: "Open1", options: [.foreground])
    let catogeryOne = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "notificationID1", actions: [actionOne], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])

    let actionTwo = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "actionTwo", title: "Open2", options: [.foreground])
    let catogeryTwo = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "notificationID2", actions: [actionTwo], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])

    let actionThree = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "actionThree", title: "Open3", options: [.foreground])
    let catogeryThree = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "notificationID3", actions: [actionThree], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([catogeryOne, catogeryTwo, catogeryThree])

    return true
}


func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    print("willPresent method called")
    completionHandler([.alert, .sound])
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    print("didReceive Method called")

    if response.actionIdentifier == "actionOne" {
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.alertAction()
        })
    } else if response.actionIdentifier == "actionTwo" {

    } else if response.actionIdentifier == "actionThree" {

    }
    completionHandler()
}



func alertAction() {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Hello", message: "This is cool!", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        // Do something with handler block
    }))

    let pushedViewControllers = (self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController).viewControllers
    let presentedViewController = pushedViewControllers[pushedViewControllers.count - 1]

    presentedViewController.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Also I have deleted all of the previous suggestions from the `viewDidLoad` and other places.

[image]

Change your connections to the `show` and do not present as modally. If you want to show your alerts everywhere. Good luck

Comment: Unfortunately after implementing the code you've suggested here the app crashed :(

Comment: I've tested. And it's well working condition. Please show your all of the codes. I need both the AppDelegate and ViewController and I'll explain how it's done

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rjx05w1m81q2fxl/SetAlarmViewController.swift?dl=0

Comment: I plan to have 3 notifications everyday. The above are the dropbox links to the source code.

Comment: Remove delegate from the viewDidLoad, you do not need anymore.

Comment: The app still crashes without the delegate in the viewDidLoad :(

Comment: There's no output even I set it to Wait for the executable to be launched. So I have to give you the entire project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ytorrytr2y9nzsf/Soul%20Meds%20copy.zip?dl=0 Just run the app, tap on Alarm and hit Next, set the first alarm and see the results.

Comment: I found a lot of problems in your project!

Comment: Please change your connections between the `viewControllers` to the `show` as suggested above. Good luck

Comment: @Mannopson Thank you for your answer, was very helpful!!

Comment: it always give me actionidenentifire = com.apple.UNNotificaionDefaultActionIdentifire

Answer (score 0):

I have Conformed to UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate inside AppDelegate. Everything is simple just *posted my notification inside async block that will run after 0.1 second*.

I am observing *Notification.Name.LocalNotificationTapped* inside my HomeViewController to update UI whenever this notification is observed *For Example to present some popup etc*

You can think about the code inside async block like you are presenting any alert or presenting any screen.

> UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    
    let notificationData = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name.LocalNotificationTapped, object: nil,userInfo: notificationData)
    }
    completionHandler()
}
```