# iOS11 handle firebase push notification when app removed from background

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios11

Code :

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
requestNotificationAuthorization(application: application)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:
    #selector(tokenRefreshNotification), name:
    NSNotification.Name.InstanceIDTokenRefresh, object: nil)

//in iOS9 called didreceiveremote method when app is killed
let notification = launchOptions?[.remoteNotification]
if notification != nil {
    self.application(application, didReceiveRemoteNotification: notification as! [AnyHashable : Any])
}

@objc func tokenRefreshNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let refreshedToken = InstanceID.instanceID().token() {
        print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")

        UserDefaults.standard.setPushToken(value:refreshedToken)
    }

}

func requestNotificationAuthorization(application: UIApplication) {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions, completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

}

extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    // iOS10+, called when presenting notification in foreground
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        NSLog("[UserNotificationCenter] applicationState: \(applicationStateString) willPresentNotification: \(userInfo)")
        //TODO: Handle foreground notification
        completionHandler([.alert])
    }

    // iOS10+, called when received response (default open, dismiss or custom action) for a notification
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        NSLog("[UserNotificationCenter] applicationState: \(applicationStateString) didReceiveResponse: \(userInfo)")
        //TODO: Handle background notification
        if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active {
            //TODO: Handle foreground notification
        } else {
            //TODO: Handle background notification

        }
        completionHandler()
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
        NSLog("[RemoteNotification] applicationState: \(applicationStateString) didReceiveRemoteNotification for iOS9: \(userInfo)")


        if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active {
            //TODO: Handle foreground notification
        } else {
            //TODO: Handle background notification

        }
    }
}
```

I am developing an app which has target of iOS9 and firebase push notification feature. My requirement is the app removed from background and the user tap push notification then move to a screen(Ex. `AccountVC`). In iOS 9 I could able to handle push notification when app is removed from background. But in iOS11 I do not know how to handle when app is removed from background. Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: ya you have the code `TODO: Handle background notification` call here

Comment: @anbu in iOS 11?..

Comment: see this for help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382852/didreceiveremotenotification-not-called-ios-10/39383027#39383027

Comment: you clearly mentioned `// iOS10+`, then you get the details from here didReceive response:

Comment: that method did not get called in ios11 when app is removed from background

Comment: i think you made the mistake somewhere else see this for help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42050324/unusernotificationcenter-didreceive-response-not-called-when-app-is-terminated